# Swagger Editor Importing spec and external refs

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am using swagger editor and have imported an openapi spec as a yaml but it shows errors due to all external refs

```
- $ref: '#/components/parameters/orgIdPathParam'
```

Which points to the definition in another file

```
  parameters:
    orgIdPathParam:
      $ref: 'api-resources-params.yaml#/orgIdPathParam'
```

Here is one of many identical errors:

```
Declared path parameter "org_id" needs to be defined as a path parameter at either the path or operation level
Jump to line 33
```

I am able to use validator badge tool to validate (https://github.com/swagger-api/validator-badge) so I know it's valid. So it seems that swagger editor is not considering the externally defined params. How can I get the externally defined params into swagger editor via yaml? I don't want to boot up the server and pass the url just to modify the openapi spec, would just want to import and edit directly.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you want to just open the spec in swagger editor then you can just grab the schemas from the api-resources-param.yaml file and add them locally to the spec. Then go through and change any reference paths to local paths.

Comment: @tomredfern I am trying to import a yaml containing an openapi spec into the swagger editor tool and have refs resolve automatically. I tried what you suggested and it did work, that's good. I had to copy paste from multiple external yamls, including api-resources-param.yaml. Also I had to make many manual search replace changes because there are more refs within those external yamls too. So I think that strategy is not sustainable since it did take some time to manually merge this composite spec.

Comment: @tomredfern the refs don't resolve automatically, but I would like to be able to, say import the external yamls containing the definitions for those refs. But the import file functionality seems to completely replace anything which was previously imported, thus only a single file can be imported

Comment: Which tool are you using? Swaggerhub or another editor?

Comment: Swagger editor on docker locally https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-editor/

Comment: you need to host those external refs where they are reachable. I'm not aware of SwaggerUI having the ability to resolve two documents without using a network reachable uri

Answer (score 0):

if you use an Id in the route you need to declare the ID right below, just before putting the method for that route. Take a look at the following for reference:

[image]